# Add a transient field to JAXB?

Tags: java, hibernate, jaxb

is it possible to add transient column to the generated XML using Java Architecture For XML Binding?
I'm using {XML Access Type.PROPERTY} .

Comment: @XmlTransient could do it ?

Comment: @XmlTransient would ignore a normal property,i want the opposite,i want to generate a TRANSIENT field of one entity ..

Comment: Did you try it? What was the outcome?

Comment: @Dragan Brozanovic It seems like it generates only the columns that are in the db,the three fields that i have  added as transient on the entity do not appear although i have added the XMLElement on their getter

Comment: @DraganBozanovic No,they are not